# Confused on how to properly use promises in http Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to using cloud functions for Firebase with an http triggered function and I am confused on how to properly terminate the function. I'm not sure if I should be using res.sendStatus, returning a promise, or both.

The goal of my function is to loop through several documents in the collection 'communities'. Each *community* has a collection of documents where I query the document with the highest value of 'hotScore'. I then send an iOS push notification containing that document to a topic (all users in that given community).

Unfortunately, I am getting several errors when the code is run such as `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` and `Unhandled rejection`. I'm pretty such this is due to my negligence in handling function termination, although I have been confused by the online resources I have looked at so far. Would someone mind taking a look at my code/pointing me in the right direction? Thank you so much!

```
exports.sendNotificationTrendingPost = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  //Get communities collection from Firestore
  return admin.firestore().collection('communities').get().then((communities) => {
    var communityPromises = [];
    //Loop through each community
    communities.forEach((community) => {
      let communityID = community.get('communityID');
      let communityName = community.get('name');
      //Get the post with the highest hotScore
      let communityPromise = admin.firestore().collection('communities').doc(communityID).collection('posts').orderBy('hotScore', 'desc').limit(1).get().then((posts) => {
        let hottestPost = posts[0];
        let postID = hottestPost.get('postID');
        let postText = hottestPost.get('text');
        let currentDate = Date.now() / 1000;
        var message;
        //Verify that the hottest post was posted in the past 24 hours
        if (hottestPost.get('date') > (currentDate - 86400)) {
          //Build the notification text (shortening if too long)
          let shortenedPostText = postText.substring(0,60);
          var textEnd = '';
          if (postText.length > 60) {
            textEnd = '...';
          }
          let notificationText = 'Trending post on ' + communityName + ': ' + shortenedPostText + textEnd;
          //Build the push notification
          message = {
            apns: {
              headers: {
                'apns-push-type': 'alert'
              },
              payload: {
                aps: {
                  alert: {
                    body: notificationText,
                  },
                },
                postID: postID,
              },
            },
            topic: communityID
          }
        }
        //Send the message and return the promise
        if (message === null) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return admin.messaging().send(message);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
      })
      if (communityPromise !== null) {
        communityPromises.push(communityPromise);
      }
    })
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return Promise.all(communityPromises);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  })
})
```

Comment: I'll come back to this later, but it should be noted that returning a `Promise` for a HTTP Request function does nothing. At first glance, you call `res.status(500).send(error)` and then `res.sendStatus(200)`. I'd consider refactoring your code to use `async`/`await` syntax here as you've entered nested-promise land which will catch you out with stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As samthecodingman advised, it is much better to use `async/await` in your case, as it will simplify the code and will make it much easier to read.

The following changes should do the trick (untested). Note how we use an Array of Community names in order to pass the names from one loop to the other. This works because, with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), the returned values are in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.

```
exports.sendNotificationTrendingPost = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const db = admin.firestore();

        const communitiesQuerySnap = await db.collection('communities').get();

        const communityPromises = [];
        const communityNames = [];

        communitiesQuerySnap.forEach((community) => {
            let communityID = community.get('communityID');
            let communityName = community.get('name');
            communityNames.push(communityName);
            communityPromises.push(db.collection('communities').doc(communityID).collection('posts').orderBy('hotScore', 'desc').limit(1).get())
        });

        const postsQuerySnapArray = await Promise.all(communityPromises);

        const messagePromises = [];
        postsQuerySnapArray.forEach((postsQuerySnap, index) => {
            const hottestPost = postsQuerySnap.docs[0];
            const postID = hottestPost.get('postID');
            const postText = hottestPost.get('text');
            const currentDate = Date.now() / 1000;
            let message;

            if (hottestPost.get('date') > (currentDate - 86400)) {
                //Build the notification text (shortening if too long)
                let shortenedPostText = postText.substring(0, 60);
                var textEnd = '';
                if (postText.length > 60) {
                    textEnd = '...';
                }

                const communityName = communityNames[index];  // The two Arrays postsQuerySnapArray and communityName have the same order, because Promise.all keeps the order.

                let notificationText = 'Trending post on ' + communityName + ': ' + shortenedPostText + textEnd;
                //Build the push notification
                message = {
                    apns: {
                        headers: {
                            'apns-push-type': 'alert'
                        },
                        payload: {
                            aps: {
                                alert: {
                                    body: notificationText,
                                },
                            },
                            postID: postID,
                        },
                    },
                    topic: communityID
                }
                messagePromises.push(admin.messaging().send(message));
            }
        })

        await Promise.all(messagePromises);
        res.status(200).send({ result: "completed" }); // Or res.end()

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }

});
```

Comment: This makes total sense - I definitely have a better understanding of promises and async/await now. Thank you so much for your time and answer! :)

Comment: One more question - I am getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined' when I call get on an element in postsQuerySnap. In my case, the error is thrown when I call hottestPost.get('postID') or hottestPost.get('text'). Do you know what is causing this issue?

Comment: It is probably because one or more communities do not have a hot score doc.  You should test if the postQuerySnap is empty or not

Comment: Hmm I verified that all communities contain a 'posts' collection and every post document has a hotScore property. The issue seems to be that every postQuerySnap in postsQuerySnapArray is of type undefined (not even an array where I could test if it is empty).

Comment: Update for anyone wondering - I solved this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922861/firebase-documents-in-collection-query-are-type-undefined/66934712#66934712

Comment: @AshtonCofer I've just realised now that it is actually caused by a mistake in my answer... sorry :-( It should be `const hottestPost = postsQuerySnap.docs[0];`and not `const hottestPost = postsQuerySnap[0];`. The [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) is not an Array. We need to use the `docs` property in order to get an Array of `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - no worries at all! Thanks so much for your help :)